# One more difference between gcc's and MS preprocessor

Tags: visual-studio, gcc, c-preprocessor

One more difference between gcc preprocessor and that of MS VS cl. Consider the following snippet:

```
# define A(x) L ## x
# define B A("b")
# define C(x) x
C(A("a" B))
```

For 'gcc -E' we get the following:

```
L"a" A("b")
```

For 'cl /E' the output is different:

```
L"a" L"b"
```

MS preprocessor somehow performs an additional macro expansion. Algorithm of its work is obviously different from that of gcc, but this algorithm also seems to be a secret. Does anyone know how the observed difference can be explained and what is the scheme of preprocessing in MS cl?

Comment: IDK what's going on but - surprise surprise - GCC's behavior is the correct.

Comment: @H2CO3 : why is gcc's behavioiur correct? what are the specs on this particular point?

Comment: @Adrien Standard specifies that recursive macro expansion should occur on every 2nd level (in order to enable stringification of tokens etc.)

Answer (score 5):

GCC is correct. The standard specifies:

> **C99 6.10.3.4/2 (and also C++98/11 16.3.4/2)**: If the name of the macro being replaced is found during this scan of the replacement list
>   (not including the rest of the source file’s preprocessing tokens), it is not replaced.

So, when expanding `A("a" B)`, we first replace `B` to give `A("a" A("B"))`.

`A("B")` is *not* replaced, according to the quoted rule, so the final result is `L"a" A("B")`.

Comment: Are the C and the C++ preprocessor specifications equal in this regard? It is worth mentioning that MS compiler is a C++ compiler whereas gcc is a c compiler.

Comment: @RedX: Good point. Yes, C++ is identical in this regard (and I think the entire preprocessor specification is identical to C).

Comment: @RedX: Both MS and GCC compilers are C++ *and* C compilers, depending on how you invoke them. The mode should be the same, unless you deliberately made a special effort to drive MS compiler into C++ mode and GCC into C mode.

Comment: @AndreyT, in the places where C and C++ differ, Microsoft has explicitly chosen to conform to C++ and ignore C. To me that justifies its classification as a C++ compiler. Don't know about gcc.

Comment: @Mark Ransom: My experience with MS C compiler is that it is indeed a dedicated C89/90 compiler, and a pretty good one (as C89/90 compiler). I'm not aware of any really bad C++ intrusions into the C mode of MS compiler. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 4):

Mike's answer is correct, but he actually elides the critical part of the standard that shows why this is so:

> **6.10.3.4/2** If the name of the macro being replaced is found during this scan of the replacement list
>   (not including the rest of the source file’s preprocessing tokens), it is not replaced.
>      Furthermore, if any nested replacements encounter the name of the macro being replaced,
>     it is not replaced. These nonreplaced macro name preprocessing tokens are no longer
>    available for further replacement *even if they are later (re)examined in contexts in which
>   that macro name preprocessing token would otherwise have been replaced.*

Note the last clause here that I've emphasized.

So both gcc and MSVC expand the macro `A("a" B)` to `L"a" A("b")`, but the interesting case (where MSVC screws up) is when the macro is wrapped by the `C` macro.

When expanding the `C` macro, its argument is first examined for macros to expand and `A` is expanded.  This is then substituted into the body of C, and then that body is then scanned AGAIN for macros to replace.  Now you might think that since this is the expansion of `C`, only the name `C` will be skipped, but this last clause means that the tokens from the expansion of `A` will also skip reexpansions of A.

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two ways of how one could think that the remaining occurrance of the A macro should be replaced:

The first would be the processing or macro arguments before they are inserted in place of the corresponding parameter in the macro's replacement list. Usually each argument is complete macro-replaced as if it formed the rest of the input file, as decribed in section 6.10.3.1
 of the standard. However, this is *not* done if the parameter (here: x) occurs next to the ##; in this case the parameter is simply replaced with the argument according to 6.10.3.3, without any recursive macro replacement.

The second way would be the "rescanning and further replacement" of section 6.10.3.4, but this not done recursively for a macro that has already been replaced once.

So neither applies in this case, which means that gcc is correct in leaving that occurrence of A unreplaced.